# CSS Flex grid with overflow in X axis

Tags: html, css, flexbox, hover, overflow

I am trying to create a grid of tiles, which sounds easy enough.
The problem I run into is that I want to have each row overflow in the X axis and each tile to expand on hover.
When the tile is expanded on hover it should only push aside its siblings, not the row above/below.

I have made a version that works, but the code is not exactly elegant and the only reason in works is using negative bottom-margins to push the lines lines together as well as setting the aspect ratio on the background image. The way I understand it this happens because Flex is trying to fit all items into it's container. I also don't quite understand how setting the aspect ratio of the image can override flexbox's need to fit everything inside the frame.

I've made a code pen of it demonstrating the code, but I would love for someone to help me coming up with a better solution since this is quite messy!

If this could be achieved in HTML and CSS only that would be great.

So here's the requirements I want to have:

- several rows with 11 tiles that overflows in the X direction without creating scrollbars so that the user can horizontal scroll on each line
- when hovering over a tile it should push the items in the same row to the side, but not the line above/below
- when hovering the tile size should increase by X%, but the content (text) should not increase in size
- the box-shadow should not be cut off by the line below when hovering

[Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/kyrregjerstad/pen/VwdYLvj)

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="tile">
      <div class="text">
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
      <img class="background-image" src="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  /* firefox */
  scrollbar-width: none;

  overflow-x: auto;
}

/* chrome */
.grid::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1vw;
  height: 12vw;
  margin-bottom: -4vw;

  overflow-y: hidden;

  /* FireFox */
  scrollbar-width: none;
}
/* chrome */
.row::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.tile {
  position: relative;

  height: 6vw;
  width: 10vw;
  transition: 350ms all;
}

.tile:hover {
  height: 8vw;
  width: 13vw;
  z-index: 2;

  box-shadow: 1vw 0.5vw 1vw #00000075;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;

  font-size: 1.5vw;
  height: 30%;

  transition: all 250ms;
}

.tile:hover .text {
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.background-image {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 50% 10%;
  aspect-ratio: 1.62/1;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: *"...the only reason in works is using negative bottom-margins to push the lines together..."* On `.row` you have the height set to `12vw` and the bottom margins set to `-4vw`. Why not removed the bottom margins and set the height to `8vw`?

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply! If I remove the bottom margin and set the height to 8 the rows are overlapping. Check it out in the codepen and you'll see what I mean!